# Create an Image object from scratch? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, image, oop, video

I want to create an image object from scratch. Here is the idea:

```
var image = new Image();
var image2 = new Object();
/* heres where the magic is
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\*/
if image = image2
    alert('sucess');
```

The goal is that I need to edit the Image object to accept video files. I suppose the solution could also be prototypical if it changed the structure of the Image object appropriately.

Comment: What are you using this for? More details would help a lot.

Comment: I just need to be able to import the image/video source/data. It is for a project called the Junkyard Jumbotron, I am trying to preserve as much of the original architecture as possible. It is opensource, here is my git repo https://github.com/JeremyRubin/Junkyard-Jumbotron/blob/master/public/javascript/jjdisplay.js check line 62. 

Thanks!

Comment: @Confused_Coder this requires HTML5 or hackery.

Comment: But there isn't a HTML5-Javascript Video object? Or would a window.document.createElement('video') work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function videotr(){
media = document.createElement('video');
media.preload = true;
//media.controls = true;
media.className = 'c1';
media.id = 'it'; 
document.getElementById('crop').appendChild(media);
//media.loop = true;
//media.autoplay = true;


return media;

}
```

this works